# Spring named "IN" query producing error when given more than one entry

Tags: java, spring, eclipselink, spring-data-jpa

I'm using Spring's named queries to access my data and came upon an issue.
I have a rather long named query in my spring data repo:

```
List<LandscapeLocationEntity> findByIdCustomerIdAndIdProductGroupAndIdProductIdAndIdLocationIdInAndActiveFlag(String customerId, String ProductGroup, String productId, List<Integer> locationId, boolean activeFlag);
```

The query works perfectly fine as long as I provide a `List<Integer>` with only one entry. As soon as there is another entry it will throw a `java.sql.SQLException: Borrow prepareStatement from pool failed`.

[image: This is the detailed error message]

As you can see in the screenshot, the call is different from the actual query (LOCATIONID(?,?) vs. LOCATIONID(?)). 
I have a workaround which just executes the queries separately but that's not the way I want to have it in the long term.

If you need further information please tell me.

**UPDATE:** 
To prove my point I removed all the other attributes and still get the same error:

[image: shortened query]

Query is now: `List<LandscapeLocationEntity> findByIdLocationIdIn(List<Integer> locations);`

Comment: Nice example of when to revert from "query from method name" to @Query :)

Comment: Did you mean because of the length or the complexity? (Updated question)

Comment: It may relate to this funky [issue](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=349477) :)

Comment: Could you try change your method name as `findByLocationIdIn`, without first **Id** right after **By**? I am asking because as your screenshots look you have 1 more bind parameter which is not, let say, handled.

Comment: I cannot rename the parameter without the Id as it is a composite key and it wouldn't be able to find the parameter without this.

Comment: @NicolasLabrot thanks for the tip. It looks like this is exactly my issue. It's a pity they didn't fix this after nearly 6 years...